# sql expert - select multiple values from multiple columns without the results repeat on itself

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking for a SQL that search in one table in few columns without the result jump twice,

```
 first_name | last_name |
------------------------
 george    |  klounie   |
 jimmi     |  parker    |
 rechard   |  klinton   |
 bill      |  klinton   |
```

What I want to do is search for two keywords array(0=>"bill",1=>"klinton")

And I want to get just the bill klinton row.

I have tried to put my php code in a loop but then I get

1st result -> bill klinton
2nd result -> [0]rechard klinton [1] bill klinton

Comment: `where first_name = 'bill' and last_name = 'klinton'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with MySQL LIKE

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME 
WHERE first_name LIKE "%bill%" 
AND last_name LIKE "%klinton%" ;
```

Comment: Exactly, but I want to get the result of AND and OR

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by "get the result of AND and OR"

Comment: Let say that I wanna get 3 result, 1st result is all where is bill AND Klingon, 2nd result is where is all Klingon, 3rd Result get me all the bill, hope I explain myself good this time :)

Comment: Okay I understand that now. One more question. Do you want to it as a single query or you it with three different queries?

Comment: What do mean by categorized? Can you be more explicit if possible with example from the sample in your question

Comment: I can't find a way to explain myself more so in different Queries it will be great, I'll use php to categorized it :), thank you.

Comment: If you can write it in multiple queries, I will use it.